# How do I escape double quotes in attributes in an XML String in T-SQL?

Tags: xml, t-sql, escaping

Pretty simple question - I have an attribute that I would like to have double quotes in.  How do I escape them?  I've tried

- \"
- ""
- \\"

And I've made the @xml variable both xml type and varchar(max) for all of them.

```
 declare @xml xml --(or varchar(max) tried both)

 set @xml = '<transaction><item value="hi "mom" lol" 
    ItemId="106"  ItemType="2"  instanceId="215923801"  dataSetId="1" /></transaction>'

 declare @xh int
 exec sp_xml_preparedocument @xh OUTPUT, @xml

 insert into @commits --I declare the table, just removed it for brevity
 select
    x.*
 from openxml(@xh,'/transaction/item')
  WITH (
    dataItemId int,
     dataItemType int,
    instanceId int,
    dataSetId int,
    value varchar(max)
  ) x
```

Comment: By the way... there is no reason (AFAIK) to use openxml here... that is "pre-2005" stuff. If you have an xml value, use it as xml directly.

Comment: Marc - Thank you.  I had another bug that ended up being openxml was busting with curly apostrophes: ’  I think I'm going to post it as a question/answer for google to find.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

Wouldn't that be `&quot;` in xml? i.e.

```
"hi &quot;mom&quot; lol"
```

**edit: ** tested; works fine:

```
declare @xml xml

 set @xml = '<transaction><item value="hi &quot;mom&quot; lol" 
    ItemId="106"  ItemType="2"  instanceId="215923801"  dataSetId="1" /></transaction>'

select @xml.value('(//item/@value)[1]','varchar(50)')
```

Answer (score 4):

tSql escapes a double quote with another double quote.  So if you wanted it to be part of your sql string literal you would do this:

```
declare @xml xml 
set @xml = "<transaction><item value=""hi"" /></transaction>"
```

If you want to include a quote inside a *value* in the xml itself, you use an entity, which would look like this:

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = "<transaction><item value=""hi &quot;mom&quot; lol"" /></transaction>"
```

Comment: Best not to use double-quotes as SQL string delimiters though. Single quotes are ANSI standard and always work, regardless of the QUOTED_IDENTIFIER setting.

Comment: Agreed, but I wanted to demonstrate that's it's possible, just in case there was any confusion about what he was trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

Cannot comment anymore but voted it up and wanted to let folks know that `&quot;` works very well for the xml config files when forming regex expressions for RegexTransformer in Solr like so: `regex=".*img src=&quot;(.*)&quot;.*"` using the escaped version instead of double-quotes.

Answer (score 2):

In Jelly.core to test a literal string one would use:

```
&lt;core:when test="${ name == 'ABC' }"&gt;
```

But if I have to check for string "Toy's R Us":

```
&lt;core:when test="${ name == &amp;quot;Toy&apos;s R Us&amp;quot; }"&gt;
```

It would be like this, if the double quotes were allowed inside:

```
&lt;core:when test="${ name == "Toy's R Us" }"&gt;
```