# SQL 2008: Insert XML value with backslash-doublequote combo

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I need to insert some xml into a SQL table column that looks like this:

```
<date format="ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \"UTC\" yyyy" />
```

SQL complains it is expecting whitespace after the double quote before the U.

```
INSERT INTO foo
(date)
VALUES ('<date format="ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \"UTC\" yyyy" />')
```

I've tried doubling the double quotes and the backslashes, but I get the same error.

Comment: There's a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650821/how-do-i-escape-double-quotes-in-attributes-in-an-xml-string-in-t-sql, the answer is to use `&quot;`

Comment: @Pedro - Presumably XML `select CAST('<date format="ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \"UTC\" yyyy" />' as XML)` gives `XML parsing: line 1, character 37, whitespace expected`.

Comment: Yes, the column is an XML type.

Comment: @thomaswilliams - I looked and didn't see that one. Probably because I didn't include the term XML in my search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML is invalid. `"` is not allowed in attribute values when you enclose the value with `"`.

Escape the `"` with `&quot;` like this

```
<date format="ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \&quot;UTC\&quot; yyyy" />
```

Or use `'` to enclose the attribute value

```
<date format='ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \"UTC\" yyyy' />
```

The result in the XML column in SQL Server is the same no matter how you do it.

```
<date format="ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \&quot;UTC\&quot; yyyy"/>
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that the problem was the XML and not the SQL. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL parameters to avoid any issues with the values you have to insert